# SQL triggers - how to get auto incremented value from inserted data of one table, inserted into another?

Tags: sql, triggers, auto-increment

I have two tables "marketplace" and "stats". I have a trigger on Inserts to marketplace that takes this new data and also inserts it into stats like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `marketplace_to_stats`
BEFORE INSERT ON `marketplace`
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO
stats (stats.studentID, stats.listingID, stats.listingName, stats.date, stats.percent, stats.listingViews, stats.listingWatching, stats.listingSales) 
VALUES(NEW.studentID, NEW.listingID, NEW.listingName, curdate(), 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

However, the listingID in the marketplace table is auto incremented, and the insert statements i use leave that column out. therefore, my trigger isn't gathering the auto incremented value from the marketplace table and instead inserts 0 each time.

How can I change this trigger statement to gather and insert to the stats table, the auto incremented value generated on the marketplace table?

Tables:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `marketplace`
--

CREATE TABLE `marketplace` (
  `listingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `studentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `listingName` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `fileName` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `listingBio` varchar(1500) NOT NULL,
  `listingPrice` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `stats`
--

CREATE TABLE `stats` (
  `studentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `listingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `listingName` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `percent` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `listingViews` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `listingWatching` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `listingSales` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You haven't shown the trigger which makes it really, really, really hard to say anything about it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry I thought I how i spoke of it in the begining was clear enough, I'll edit the code to include the full statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want auto-generated columns, then use an `after insert` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `marketplace_to_stats`
AFTER INSERT ON `marketplace`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO stats (studentID, listingID, listingName, date, percent, listingViews, listingWatching, listingSales) 
    VALUES (NEW.studentID, NEW.listingID, NEW.listingName, curdate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
END;
```

Although MySQL allows the columns in the `insert` to be qualified, I find that is unnecessary (and incompatible with other databases).